# PHP while loop returning null result

Tags: php, mysql

```
$connect_status = "SELECT connected_to_id FROM tbl_connect WHERE user_id = 
{$_SESSION['user_id']}";

$exec_connstatus_query = mysql_query($connect_status, $db_connect);

while($check_status = mysql_fetch_array($exec_connstatus_query))
{   
  if ($check_status['connected_to_id'] == $profileid)
  {
    echo "{$check_status['connected_to_id']}";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "fail";
  }
}
```

This code has been troubling me for 3 hours. Here the issue is even if this condition:

`if ($check_status['connected_to_id'] == $profileid)`

returns false, I am not able to see "fail" when the `else` statement executes. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the loop is being executed?

Comment: What kind of values can be in that connected_to_id field, and what's the value in $profileid? PHP will consider many comparison to be TRUE, even though any reasonable person wouldn't, e.g. the field in the database is NULL, and $profileid is `0` or an empty string.

Comment: Is this all your code? if you echo $check_status['connected_to_id'] and $profileid, what do they show? Should there be another '}' to close the while loop, or is it just missed in the question.

Comment: Is the first line with {} a valid php syntax? Can someone confirm?

Comment: @subirkumarsao: yes, it's valid. it's PHP syntax for embedding "complex" vars into double-quoted strings. e.g. `$x ="$arr[a][b]"` would normally fail because PHP's parser isn't gready and would only treat `$arr[a]` as an array, followed by a couple brackets and a b. using {} around the whole thing forces php to treat both bracket bits as part of the array dereference.

Comment: If neither echo is printing anything, then your query probably returned zero results and your loop did not run.

Comment: @VanDarg Yes the loop is getting executed, I'll tell u what happens, say for example USER A clicks on connect on USER B profile, USER A & USER B ID gets saved in the database, now USER A connects USER C, this is the logic, but id user A goes to user B profile and assume that user A has got no connections else statement should be printed on user B's profile or C as user A has got no connection, but if user A connects to any 1 user say b or c the other profile he visits is reflected by else statement ..

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: I mean i don't see any issue in my code but if the array returns 0 and while loop should not be performed, instead it should throw else statement but it throws else only when array is returned 1 for a particular profile and 0 for another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to check `$exec_connstatus_query` first, because it may be that your query is not executed properly and thats why control did not go inside while loop. And your response is null. Print $exec_connstatus_query and check first.
Or in case if query return Zero records, in that case loop won't run.

Comment: Thanks! btw I am from India, wanna join for a project?

Answer (score 1):

mysql_query() returns FALSE on error and the loop won't execute at all.  This would occur if $_SESSION['user_id'] is not numeric.  why not just

```
$connect_status = "SELECT connected_to_id FROM tbl_connect WHERE user_id ='$_SESSION[user_id]'";
```

Ditto mysql_fetch_array() returns FALSE if there are no (more) rows.  If your session doesn't exist in **tbl_connect** then the loop won't execute.  Don't you want something like:

```
$connect_status = "SELECT connected_to_id FROM tbl_connect 
                   WHERE user_id ='$_SESSION[user_id]' LIMIT 1";
$exec_connstatus_query = mysql_query($connect_status, $db_connect);
if( ($check_status = mysql_fetch_array($exec_connstatus_query)) && 
    ($check_status['connected_to_id'] == $profileid) ) {
    echo "{$check_status['connected_to_id']}";
} else {
    echo "fail";
}
```

Comment: my Q status now is "edited ***edited 53 mins ago***"answered **1 hour ago**" Yr comment was timestamped an hr ago => you made a comment so I updated my answer accordingly.